# No access or error logging on OpenSuse

Tags: amazon-ec2, opensuse, logging

I've got an Amazon ec2 instance running OpenSuse and I'm getting a white page of death on some of my php scripts but there's no error log in var/log/apache2. To my surprise, there's also no access log.

Is this disabled by default? How do I enable error and access logging?

Edit:

In case this helps, when I set display_errors in php.ini to On, it displays this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /srv/www/htdocs/application/controllers/browse.php on line 165

But it doesn't get logged anywhere that I can find.

Comment: Are you sure it's not somewhere else like /var/log/httpd?

Comment: /var/log/httpd does not exist on my server. Looks like OpenSuse does everything under 'apache2' but there's no access or error log there.